# URL Rewriting in PHP and Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site developed in php and now I am almost at the end of launching it but just want to make the URL user-friendly. My site is dynamic and in links which is dynamically created has query string in URL so now how can I make it user-friendly URL.

I want url like this `http://www.example.com/results?show=first&tid=6409b45eea365c3919034a8b`

Here is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(home|about-us|contact-us|login)?$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^results?([0-9]+)$ index.php?show=$1&tid=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Here is php code

```
$file = protect(trim(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
switch($file) {
    
    case "home" : include("sources/home_page.php"); break;
    case "about-us" : include("sources/about.php"); break;
    case "login" : include("sources/login.php"); break;
    case "contact-us" : include("sources/contact.php"); break;




    case "logout" : include("controller/logout.php"); break;

    case "results" : include("controller/serach-result.php"); break;


    

    
    default: include("sources/home.php");
}
```

If  I try to access http://example.com/home ,about-us, login, contact-us all working fine

But when I try to access http://example.com/results?show=first&tid=545454dfdffd I

t redirect me to http://example.com/home

Tried many ways but unable to short it out

Comment: First of all, which is it - `results`, or `result`? Second - RewriteRule matches against the _path_ component of the URL only.

Comment: This is really something you ought to have built into the design from the beginning. It's a key part of the architecture, not an afterthought

Comment: @ADyson home,about-us,login all working fine but results?show=first&tid=dfkdfdhdffdh 

not working it redirect to home

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess, you can try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It redirect all the request to index, and then your router can handle the request uri.

It's better to do it directly into your server configuration if you have access to (for example, 000-default.conf on Ubuntu/Debian), because .htaccess slow down your websites, as you can see here :
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

Instead of `protect(trim(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));`
you can use `$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and pass the uri var to your switch case